# Little girl on alien planet with her father; purple aliens jump between trees using their tails

Tags: story-identification, novel

Does anyone remember the title of a novel in which a little girl is on an alien planet with her father? I can't remember details but I know that the alien natives were purple, incredibly fast and would jump between trees using their tails. At one point the girl gets onto an alien's back and experiences what it's like to jump between the trees. The father's science camp was destroyed by another race of aliens.  I'm fairly certain its a young adult novel.